# I want to preview my view in my first app to other app i've created

Tags: android

This if the first app and want to preview this in the second app,i'm using this but it doesn't work

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setPackage("com.pimpimp.passenger");
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? You are trying to view your first app in your second app???

Comment: i want to do something like when i click on a button start my stopwatch from the first application start and i want to show the stopwatch in the first application in the second application

Comment: this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/15465797/7200713 might help you.